# How to send Control+C to UART serial port?

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am trying to automate my test process where I send some commands to Linux core on my TI board via putty terminal and as response, I see console print on putty from the core. I am automating this using python and pyserial. I have a problem where some of the output prints are very large and sometimes will not stop until <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed. I am currently doing it manually but How can I automate it?

I have tried :

```py
serial.write(r'\x03' + '\n')
serial.write(b'\x03')
```

Comment: What errors do you get? `serial` is the name of the module, not a good name for your connection variable. I call mine `conn`. In that case, does `conn.write(b'\x03')` not work? This works for me. I suspect your issue is with naming.